# HTML content isnt showing up

Tags: html, css

So this is my 2'nd HTML project. I've made a fullscreen image at the top of my portfolio page with some intro text. but when i try to make another div below the image so the user can scroll down and view more content, anything i put within that div docent show up on screen at all. see for yourself.

https://codepen.io/CarbCode/pen/KWweBL

My code:

> HTML

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?

family=Lato:100|Palanquin+Dark:500" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div id="header" class="container-fluid">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mqxeqa/BG1.jpg" alt="BG1" class="headerBg">
  <h1 class="text-white" style="font-family:'Palanquin Dark'; padding-left: 5%;">Hey, I'm Carlos </h2> 
<h1 class="secondTit text-white typewriter" id="Typewrite"style="font-family:'Lato';"><i>Developer in Training/></i></h2>
<a href="#"><p id="learnmore"style="color: #a19f9f;"><i>View my portfolio</i><br/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&#8595;<p><a>
</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block1">
      <i class="fa fa-free-code-camp"></i>
```

> CSS

```
#header {
  position: relative;
}

.headerBg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  hight: 85%;
}

.typewriter {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: .01em;
  animation: typing 2s steps(50, end), blink-caret 1.2s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 6rem;
  padding-top: 16.5%;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

#learnmore {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding-top: 44%;
  padding-left: 40%;
  line-height: 0.9
}

.secondTit {
  padding-top: 25%;
  padding-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Are you missing content? Looks like your HTML was cut off, and I don't see any text after "view my portfolio"

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your code first. a)Your code missing of `<head>`; b) For each `<h1>` your have a `</h2>` as the closing tag; c) if your 'another' div means `<div class="row">`, you have an incomplete code without any `</div>`. To answer your question, not sure what css framework you are using, but I think the `<div class="row">` should be within the `<div class="container-fluid">` like this:

```
<div id="header" class="container-fluid">
   <!-- some content -->
   <div class="row">
     <!-- content for the row -->
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <!-- content for another row -->
   </div>
</div>
```

As a new learner, you should develop a habit of not mixing html with css code, for example, you should put all the styling for the two `<h1>` in css style sheet than in the html, it make the code much cleaner.